# Fill a contour with colour

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, colors, contour

I plotted a 2 sigma C.L ellipse using contour plot function in matplotlib. However I am unable to fill it with colours. Only the boundaries are coloured.

```
plt.contour(x, y, likelihood, [level1,level2])
```

Where `x=[100,], y=[100,] and l=[100,100]` dimensional arrays. The plot I get is as shown below : I would like the ellipses to be of solid colour. How to do it ? using cmap doesnt help either as posted in some other threads in this forum.

[image]

Comment: `plt.contourf()`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @kwinkunks here is a solution

```
plt.contourf(x, y, likelihood, [level1,level2],colors=['white', 'grey', 'red'],extend='both')
```